# Cannot get crash report in monitor

Tags: android, android-studio, camera

I have an app that includes using the default camera to collect a simple picture. It was developed using a Motorola phone connected to Android Studio (1.5.1), logs and crash reports appearing in Android Monitor as expected.

However, when I connect a Nexus 7 to Android Studio I see log messages in Monitor but the app then crashes and I don't see a crash report. On the Nexus screen there is a dialog box saying 'Unfortunately camera has stopped' and there are 2 options: Ok and Report. If I select report it goes to a feedback page that appears to be about to send data to Google. I have no crash info in Android Monitor.

It's crashing at the point where the Camera app is returning data to my app (I don't see the log message at the start of onActivityResult). So I imagine my app is communicating correctly with Monitor and the default Camera app isn't.

Unfortunately when I run it with a Nexus 7 emulator everything works fine! Using the camera independently on the Nexus also works fine. I just need to be able to see normal crash info in the Monitor.

Things I've tried.

- Toggling on/off USB debugging
- Revoke USB debugging authorisations
- Power menu bug reports on/off
- Select debug app set to my app and to nothing (I tried to set it to Camera but it didn't give that option)
- Switching between MTP and PTP
- Restarting Nexus/Android Studio/PC

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have selected to log the correct device?

Comment: Can I have information about your Build Variant?

Comment: Yes, connected. I see log messages before crash. Android Studio is 1.5.1 build #AI-141.2456560 built on December 1, 2015.

Comment: which Motorola is it? On some devices is an option to enable/disable. But these settings are only reachable through a number code that you have to add in the phone dialer...

Comment: open the dialer, and put in following code ***#872564#** ....I can´t guarantee that it works on all Motorola devices, but with this code, you enable/disable the log. If it is disabled, only system logs are shown...

Comment: Sorry guys but everything is fine with the Motorola. It's the Nexus 7 I have a problem with. Running the app on that gives a few log messages but then no crash report.